# killing a background process with shell in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, background

I tried killing a process with shell in Ubuntu which is created with like:

```
#!/bin/bash
<!--There should be codes which can kill my app(run in the background)
echo "app will be run." 
java -jar path/to/my/jar/file.jar /arguman/of/myApp.txt & << 'ENDAPP'
disown ENDAPP
```

I know how to kill an app with manuel which is like:

ps -ax -u| grep appName

and find processid then,

kill [processId]

Is it possible to do?İf yes,how?
Thank you.

Comment: I need a bash script to kill this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually find examples of how to do this *right here,* on this site, by doing a simple search.  (Or Google it: "bash shell wait.")  When you execute any background process, you can get the PID ("process id") of the new child.  You can wait on the child to finish.  You can also kill it.

Shell commands that show you executing `jobs` also provide their PID.

However, bear in mind that "killing a child" ... while it won't land you in *prison* in this case **;-)** ... "is generally not a good thing to do."  You have no idea what the child was doing, what it had or had not finished doing, what data might now be in an inconsistent state, when you put that bullet through its brain.  It is impossible to reliably debug any process that relies on murdering its children.

You can "send a *different* signal," such as `SIGHUP` or `SIGUSR1`, to a process, using the same `kill` command, and design the child process to be listening for that signal as an indication that it must "shut *itself* down, quickly."  Always give a process a signal to "put *its own* affairs in order, and then to *leave* 'this mortal coil' ..."